# Order of jQuery events different in IE/Chrome, how to get around this?

Tags: jquery, html, google-chrome, internet-explorer

I am writing some code that contains 3 radio buttons. I need to have the usual radio button behaviour, plus the ability to deselect them altogether. My solution involves a jQuery hook into the click event that checks if the last radio button clicked is the current one, and if it is a hidden 4th radio button is checked.

The problem is that IE fires change then click, but chrome fires click then change.

I have reproduced the problem here: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/anoL6wqp/2/)

```
<input type="radio" value="1" name="name">
<input type="radio" value="2" name="name">
<input type="radio" value="3" name="name">
```

```
var lastInput;
$('input[name="name"]').change(function(){
    console.log("change fired");
    lastInput = $(this).val();
}).click(function(){
    console.log("click fired");
    if(lastInput == $(this).val()){
        $('input[value="4"]').prop("checked", true);
        lastInput = "4";
    }
})
```

Comment: Being able to deselect a radio button is non-standard behaviour. Use checkboxes with business logic to ensure only a maximum of one can be selected. What you have now is a hacky workaround at best.